# PHP: How to convert time

Tags: php, data-conversion

**How to convert time with php?**

the original format was like `00:02:34 min`.

I need to get a echo like `154`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
   $time = '00:00:34';
   list ($days, $hours, $minutes) = split(":", $time, 3);
   $timestamp = mktime ($hours+1, $minutes, 0, $days+1, 1, 1970, FALSE);
   $minutes = $timestamp / 60;
   print $minutes;
   print "\n";`
```

(edit: `date_default_timezone_set` added)

Comment: hi, why the resault is `-386` not `34`? Thanks

Comment: Obviously a locale issue (aka 'works for me'), I feel like american now, unaware of the rest of the world. :-)

@yuli I think this edit should fix it. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myTime="00:02:34 min";
$bodytag = str_replace(" min", "", $myTime);
$myTime=explode(":",$myTime);

function timeToSeconds($hours,$minutes,$seconds){
   return $seconds+($minutes*60)+($hours*3600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey yuli chika,
I'll suggest you check out php's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) functions in the manual.  From there you can also learn about string to time functions like, well, `strtotime()` and [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php);

Date and time allow you to specify a format and a timestamp for output.  The reference for the format codes are listed in the manual links I gave above.  If you don't have a timestamp, you can use `strtotime()` to create one.